# List TXT records for a domain with Windows nslookup

Tags: nslookup

I want to inspect TXT records for my domain, such as SPF records. I tried the following command with nslookup but it didn't list the TXT records:

```
nslookup -type=TXT example.com
```

What is the correct command, or is there a better tool use on Windows 7?

Comment: The command above works but villagevines.com has no TXT records however www.villagevines.com does.

Comment: Please see answer by WilfriedVS, which works as a charm

Comment: Not sure if this parameter available on Windows 7, but on Windows 10 `nslookup -q=txt example.com` works for me.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

First start `nslookup` without parameters, then type `set type=txt`, then type the domain name.

```
nslookup <enter>
set type=txt <enter>
villagevines.com
```

#### Example

```
C:\Users\wilfried>nslookup

Default Server:  mydnsserver
Address:  192.168.1.1

> set type=txt

> villagevines.com

Server:  mydnsserver

Address:  192.168.1.1

*** No text (TXT) records available for villagevines.com

>
```

Comment: This is the real answer to the question and should be marked as such!

Comment: Updated to use this as the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but maybe because I'm looking up a `.no` domain?

Answer (score 19):

I have no ideea why but if you add an IP of a nameser at the end it will work.
I have added google's dns name in this case:

nslookup -type=TXT villagevines.com 8.8.8.8

It can be your local DNS service.

HTH next time when you need to query your TXT records.

Comment: The last parameter is the DNS to use. Maybe the default is to use the ISPs and that DNS is caching old data. This might work soon after a DNS TXT record change.

Comment: If you type : 
nslookup /? 

will see :  nslookup [-opt ...] host server # just look up 'host' using 'server'

Answer (score 7):

The link for Get-Dns does not work, the standard Powershell cmdlet to do this is

`PS> Resolve-DnsName villagevines.com -Type TXT`

[See more on Resolve-DnsName](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590781.aspx)

Comment: That only works on Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1, question was about Windows 7

Comment: If you run this internally and want to see external, you can add the `-server <remote NS IP>` to get external records similar to how nslookup command with the lserver works e.g. `Resolve-DnsName villagevines.com -Type TXT -Server 8.8.8.8`. Thank you for this answer +1.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows 10, this work:

```
nslookup -q=TXT villagevines.com
```

Update: At this moment 2021-03-29, in Windows 10, you can use old nslookup syntax

```
nslookup -type=TXT villagevines.com
```

Answer (score 5):

Download [**BIND for Windows**](http://www.isc.org/downloads), there is a Windows port of `dig` in that.  You should use dig instead of nslookup.

If you're a Powershell fan (like me) you can also download the [**Powershell Dig Cmdlet**](http://huddledmasses.org/powershell-dig-nslookup-cmdlet/) which should get TXT records for you directly within powershell.  Good stuff.

```
PS> Get-Dns -Name mydomain.com -Type TXT
```